# Saving ".out" file in Excel format

Tags: python, excel, dynamic, psse

I am running a dynamic simulation in python. My output file is in `.out` format. I want to save bus voltage 1101 in excel format.

How can I do it with programming in python.

My code is as follow:-

```
import os,sys
PYTHONPATH = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE32\PSSBIN'

sys.path.append(PYTHONPATH)
os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + PYTHONPATH

import psspy
from psspy import _i
from psspy import _f
import redirect

# Redirect output from PSSE to Python:
redirect.psse2py()

# Last case:
CASE = r"C:\Users\N.JAHAN\Desktop\2015_RVS_Test_System.sav"
psspy.psseinit(12000)
psspy.case(CASE)

# Convert loads (3 step process):
psspy.conl(-1,1,1)
psspy.conl(-1,1,2,[0,0],[100,0,0,100])
psspy.conl(-1,1,3)

# Convert generators:
psspy.cong()

# Solve for dynamics
psspy.ordr()
psspy.fact()
psspy.tysl()

# Save converted case
case_root = os.path.splitext(CASE)[0]
psspy.save(case_root + "_C.sav")

# Add dynamics data
psspy.dyre_new(dyrefile=r"C:\Users\N.JAHAN\Desktop\2015_RVS_Test_System - 
Copy.dyr")

# Add channels by subsystem
#   BUS VOLTAGE

psspy.chsb(sid=0,all=1, status=[-1,-1,-1,1,13,0])

# Add channels individually
#   load active and reactive power
psspy.load_array_channel([-1,1,1101],'1')
psspy.load_array_channel([-1,2,1101],'1')

# Save snapshot
psspy.snap(sfile="C:\Program Files 
(x86)\PTI\PSSE32\EXAMPLE\python_test.snp")
#psspy.dynamics_solution_param_2([_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i],[_f,_f, 
0.002,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f])
# Initialize
psspy.strt(outfile="C:\Program Files 
(x86)\PTI\PSSE32\EXAMPLE\python_test.out")
psspy.run(tpause=1)

# 3-phase fault on bus 201 (default bus fault is a 3phase and there is no 
bus 200)
psspy.dist_bus_fault(ibus=103)

# Run to 5 cycles
time = 1+(5.0/60.0)
psspy.run(tpause=time)

# Clear fault (assuming only part of bus faults)
psspy.dist_clear_fault()
psspy.dist_branch_trip(ibus=103, jbus=109, id='1')
#psspy.dist_machine_trip(3011,'1')

# Run to 10 seconds
time = 5
psspy.run(tpause=time)
```

Please answer I really need it. when the simulation is finished, I want to see bus voltage 1101 in an Excel file. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by - `in excel format`.  Do you want an actual .xls/.xlsx file or just csv data?

Comment: I need an actual .xls file.

Comment: Have you consulted the [Python for PSSE help forum](https://psspy.org/psse-help-forum/questions/)??

Comment: https://psspy.org/psse-help-forum/question/668/out-output-file-excel/

Comment: No, I don't know anything about it.

Comment: Ok,Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you know about saving just csv data, please help me.

Comment: The usual ways for writing Excel files with Python are to use either XlsxWriter or OpenPyXL.

Comment: Read about [14.1.4. Writer Objects  simplest possible writing example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects). Your `psse` have to be List of Column Data.